# RPi SD 'sync' time

Tags: sd-card, fstab

It seems that the RPi does not necessarily write data to the SD very promptly and data loss can occur if the power is pulled after a write operation; even after a few minutes or longer.
this can be easily demonstrated with something simple like `ls > DEMO` and then pulling the power within a second or so. On power up, DEMO will not be there. `ls > DEMO && sync` and power-cycle and the file will be there.
If the fs is mounted 'sync' then the file is also intact, but this doesn't seem to be an ideal solution. Is there a way to not have to mount 'sync', but reduce the time taken to (auto)sync?

The above demo is harsh, but a delayed sync by only a few seconds would be acceptable, the seemingly quite long wait at the moment is frustrating. (and I realise that 'don't pull the power, use a proper shutdown' is a solution, but this cannot be enforced in the environment these are used!)

Thanks,

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Pi specific problem.  Seems to be a more general Linux question.

Comment: see also: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85181/syncing-to-sd-card-is-too-slow

Answer (score 1):

You want to have your cake and eat it too:

> If the fs is mounted 'sync' then the file is also intact, but this doesn't seem to be an ideal solution.
>
> [...]
>
> I realise that 'don't pull the power, use a proper shutdown' is a solution, but this cannot be enforced in the environment these are used!

It may be worth noting that there *are no operating systems which can satisfy these criteria, period* because it is a logical impossibility.

Either:

1. You do your best to ensure a proper shutdown. If the environment poses a problem, this may mean you need need to add circuitry and a small battery.  Or...
2. You use a read-only filesystem.  Or...
3. You keep the filesystem synced to hardware, which is a potential performance hit.

That's it.  This is literally physics.  There is no possibility for a magic bullet.  There are no devices in existence which are a magical exception to this reality.

I'm not sure if using sync affects reads, but I would doubt it.  The OS caches things like shared libraries in memory largely read-only to start with, so you should not suffer too much that way.  It is only applications that have to write data to storage that will be affected.

However...

> a delayed sync by only a few seconds would be acceptable

This is plausible using an ext3/4 filesystem.  Instead of using `sync` in the mount options, use `commit=N`, where N is a number of seconds. This is documented in `man filesystems`:

> **commit=nrsec**
>
> Start a journal commit every nrsec seconds.  The default value is 5 seconds.  Zero means default.

If you look under "ext4" in that manual page, you will see other options such as `max_batch_time`; if you are doing a lot of writing, fine tuning these may be helpful.

Of course, since the default commit time is 5 seconds, this does not explain the behaviour you are seeing on the scale of minutes.  That being the case, simply changing the time will probably not solve the problem.  A potential complication is the use of "erase blocks" by SD media: These are commonly 4 MB or more.  When a change is made to a file which doesn't occupy an entire block, the entire block where it resides is re-written, which could include pretty much anything from whatever filesystem (including metadata).  If you suddenly kill the power to the card (which has its own microcontroller inside) during this re-write process, you stand to lose data in a random way.  Unfortunately the cards are a black box to the OS, so there is no possible strategy here; even keeping the filesystem synced does not remove the risk.  The only solution in this case is to either use a read-only system, or add power loss prevention circuitry.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply; yes, cake and eat it please :) but seriously, I realise the example I gave was unrealistic, it was just a handy way to illustrate the conditions. commit=N would seem to be the thing, although I'm surprised that the default 5s is not enough in the situation that is being described to me. I will have to investigate further. Thanks again.

Comment: I added a final paragraph about this.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi, your insights appreciated. thanks. One other thread I was reading was talking about the same 4MB block and how that may be an issue. The symptom as described to me is a file being opened, written and closed (in Python) but then after a power cycle the file being present, but empty. (0-length). mounting 'sync' seems to have solved this, even for 'instantaneous' switch-offs. I want to try some experiments not on a production system to try and capture the apparent total-loss.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to run `sync` from a script or a `cron` job every X seconds. Such a script can be activated and deactivated on demand, so that you can avoid the performance hit if you stop it e.g. before installing software updates.